# Glue Dynamic Frame Parse text file with ¶ delimiter

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I have a text file which look like below.

```
HDR¶20200101
BDY¶1¶Jimmy
BDY¶1¶Something
TRL¶123
```

I would like to parse it to a Glue Dynamic Dataframe by filtering out the header trailer. Also assign the header as ID, Name.  I tried the below code and it doesn't seem to work.

```
  dyf_test = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
format_options={"withHeader": False, "separator": "¶"},
connection_type="s3",
format="csv",
connection_options={
    "paths": [
        "s3://Files/test.gz"
    ],
    "recurse": True,
})




dyf_test = Filter.apply(
    frame=dyf_test,
     f=lambda row: (
        bool(re.match("HDR", row[0]))
        and bool(re.match("TRL", row[0]))
    )
)
```

Error :  com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.FatalException: Unable to parse file: test.gz

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8 encoding the separator string or using Apache Spark DataFrame?

Comment: @AndrewNguonly - Yes, I managed to get it working through Spark DF. But I am trying to figure out the Dynamic Dataframe code for the same.